# Q: Selenium webdriver submits click twice in IE11

Tags: .net, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am writing selenium tests in a .net environment for IE11.

I use IEDriverServer `2.53.1.0` and NuGet packages Selenium.Support (`v2.53.1`) and Selenium.WebDriver (`v2.53.1`).

I am using Protractor Version `0.0.6`.

When I try to click a link which contains more than one parameter, 
e.g. http://localhost/test?a=1&b=2 
then this link is clicked twice by the web driver.

If I run the test with the Chromedriver everything works fine (the link is only clicked once).

Has anybody experienced this problem? Is there a fix/workaround?
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Protractor is currently at version 4.0.9. There might be API mismatch when using Protractor 0.0.6 and the selenium standalone server 2.53.1.

Comment: According to the Nuget info the current protractor package is of version 0.8.2, which requires Selenium.WebDriver >= 2.53.0. So I guess this should work.

Comment: Okay this is a protractor-net project. Completely different than the actual protractor project.